# InvalidCastException when passing a mocked dependency into a function

Tags: vb.net, nunit, rhino-mocks, .net

I am using Rhino Mocks along with nUnit to attempt to test my function `IsApprovable()` on an object. The function I am testing relies on another object "UserManager" that needs to be passed in. I am attempting to mock an instance of UserManager so I can specify the result of another function `GetApproverDependantsList()`

My issue is that when I mock the object and pass it into the function I am testing I get the following InvalidCastException:

**Unable to cast object of type 'Castle.Proxies.IUserManagerProxye15b431a53ca4190b7ffbdf5e241e2bb' to type 'MyNamespace.Users.UserManager'**.

I am new to this so I am not really sure if I am doing things correctly... Here is the sample mocking code I am using:

```
Dim helper As New BookingManagerHelper()
Dim booking As Booking = GetDummyBooking() 'method to get a booking in suitable state
Dim parameters As Collection(Of Parameter) = GetDummyParameters() 'factory method, as above
Dim mockedUserManager = MockRepository.GenerateMock(Of Users.IUserManager)()

'I have created a dummy function called GetUserCollectionWithDependant() to create the results I need the mocked function to return...
mockedUserManager.Stub(Function(x) x.GetApproverDependantsList(-1)).[Return](GetUserCollectionWithDependant(1))

'It's the line below where I find my exception...
Assert.AreEqual(True, helper.IsApprovable(booking, mockedUserManager, parameters))
```

The function I am attempting to test looks like the following:

```
Public Function IsApprovable(ByVal Booking As Booking , ByVal UserManager As Users.UserManager, Optional ByVal Parameters As Collection(Of Parameter) = Nothing) As Boolean
'various logic checks are performed on the objects passed in
End Function
```

Some things to note:

- UserManager implements the interface IUserManager
- UserManager contains additional properties and functions that are not defined by the interface
- UserManager also inherits from a base class (do I need to override base properties?)

I can post more code if needed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am no expert in VB.NET but `IsApprovable` expects a `UserManager` instance. The mock is of type `IUserManager`. Maybe you want to adjust `IsApprovable` to use a `IUserManager` instance.